# Compiz with Intel video card not working after upgrade to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, compiz, intel-graphics, intel

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 from 10.10, my compiz configuration stopped working - I have no cube effects and preview files and some other compiz stuff.

I have a Intel x4500 (00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03))

`glxinfo`

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: Brian Paul
server glx version string: 1.4 Mesa 7.11-devel
```

I have removed `compiz` `gnome` (with --purge) and install again, nothing works.

I'm using the default Ubuntu desktop (no unity)

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Compiz is disabled by default if you're using classic desktop.

First you need to disable Ubuntu Unity Plugin from CompizConfigSettings-manager.

Then you can run compiz with:

```
compiz --replace
```

You may also want to make a startup task to run compiz every time you boot Ubuntu.

You can do this from Preferences -> Startup Applications

Answer (score 0):

Same card here. Open the terminal and type:

```
unity --reset
```

It will reset the profiles in compiz and everything should work as expected on a default behaviour.

If you want to enable the cube, ccsm has a bug. Here's my profile with the cube enabled to just load it into the unity profile in ccsm.

http://ubuntuone.com/p/sOi/

Comment: I have to say, if you just want gnome with compiz effects, this command also reset the default profile for it too.

Comment: I don't use unity just classic desktop

Comment: that doesn't matter. That command reset all the profiles (Unity and Classic Gnome) for Compiz. Now you're using Compiz 0.9 instead of 0.8 a reset doesn't hurt and you can configure compiz the way you want after that.

Comment: tryed and this waht I got :(

Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Software rendering detected
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session

Comment: Yeah, that's the usual. But i guess after doing that and restart, you're having the same problem, right?

Comment: yes still no compiz features on my desktop :\